# Mounting WD external hard drive mybook

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, external-hdd

UPDATE:

When I put in dmesg after plugging the external hd in, the output is the following (last lines):

```
[15233.307914] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[15233.307916] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[15233.307917] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[15233.307918] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[15233.307919] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm)
[15233.307920] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
[15394.090119] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[15394.106839] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=1230
[15394.106847] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[15394.106851] usb 4-1: Product: My Book 1230
[15394.106854] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[15394.106857] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 574343344531393833393336
[15394.107831] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[15394.108012] scsi8 : usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[15395.107038] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Book 1230     1050 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[15395.107393] scsi 8:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1050 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[15395.108018] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[15395.108240] ses 8:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
[15395.108424] ses 8:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 13
[15395.109767] ses 8:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x8000002
[15395.109778] ses 8:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
[15395.110499] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
```

Tried to find a solution to my question by looking first to the questions already asked about it, but couldn't find anything suitable, some I'm trying my luck:

Got an external hard drive (mybook western digital) by someone who didn't know I'm using Linux. Of course, when I just plug in through the USB slot, the hard drive seems to work (so no visible/hearable defect here), but my Ubuntu (13.10) doesn't recognize it (doesn't appear as a pop-up, nor in the file commander/explorer).

I got already so far in my knowledge that most probably the reason is that I have to mount the hard drive first.

I did already the following commands (from other forums and suggestions) and got the following results:

`~# lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0489:d601 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 08ff:168f AuthenTec, Inc. AES1660 Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 1058:1230 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
root@daniel-SVS1512Z9EB:~# apt-cache policy cifs-utils
cifs-utils:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:6.0-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
     2:6.0-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
```

as well as `~# ls /dev/sd*`

```
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda5  /dev/sdb  /dev/sdb1
root@daniel-SVS1512Z9EB:~# fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000a4fe5

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758  1953523711   976510977    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5          501760  1953523711   976510976   83  Linux
```

So now I've got two questions:

1. Providing that it really is only the mounting I have to do, how do I do it best?
2. Do I then have to "unmount" it every single time as well? If so, how to do that?

Thanks a lot in advance and best regards,

Daniel

Comment: `lsusb` sees “Bus 004 Device 003: ID 1058:1230 Western Digital Technologies, Inc.”. What's the output of `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/usb-*`? You could also try `palimpsest` aka „Gnome Disks”.

Comment: ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/usb-*
ls: cannot access /dev/disk/by-id/usb-*: No such file or directory

Comment: What's the output of `dmesg` just after plugging the external drive in?

Answer (score 0):

Just crate a new partition-table(msdos) and a new partition with gparted.
That was the solution for my automount-problem

Comment: To create an MS-DOS partition table, simply run `mkfs.msdos /dev/path/to/disk` For more information, see https://www.howtogeek.com/443342/how-to-use-the-mkfs-command-on-linux/